# Can't get google map to display in nested div

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myApikey">
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  // Create the map.
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7051364, -74.3531065),
    zoom: 10
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
  }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #2a2a2a;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: CMArial;
}
.Container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 1235px;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 0;
}
.Content {
    width: 960px;
    height: 850px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    left: 25px;
    top: 130px;
    z-index: 99;
}
</style>
<body>
<center>
<div class="Container">
<div class="Content">
    <div id="map" style="width:400px;height:400px;">
        <div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can't get map to display in div, I would like to keep both divs are they are part of the layout of my page. The "map" div I could do with or without, I'm just looking for a way to have this map on my page with a given height and width. So far nothing I have tried has worked. There is more code on my page but this is all of the relevant code. Any help would be much appreciated. From here I'm going to try to get polygons for three counties on the map, but first I've got to get the map to display. I already have the polygon data for the counties.

Comment: Your style tag isn't closed correctly (it is closed with `</script>`, not `<style>`)

Comment: Why do you have to use a nested div at all when inner-div fills parent-div out completely?

Comment: your body, center, and html tags arent closed. You have "myApikey" at the end of your googlemaps code. Thats not an api key

Comment: If I fix that, [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/55zfkga0/)

Answer (score 0):

updated with actual script, I had missed the end style tag, that was a typo while formatting for this question, but it did point this line out to me that when fixed solved my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myApikey">
```

closed out it reads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myApikey"></script>
```

thank you all for help in pointing that stuff out.